# Get value from ng-repeat key, value pair on POST Request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently working on with a form that would get values from a json object. I'm done with it! (yey~) BUT when I POST the value I couldn't get anything. value="{{key}}" doesn't return a real data after POST. Any body can help me through solving this issue? Thanks alot!

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="firewallForm" novalidate ng-init="firewallInit()">   
<div class="form-group">
                <label  class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="firewallSource">Source</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-md-2" ng-controller="entitiesController">
                    <select class="form-control input-medium" ng-model="firewallSource" ng-required="true">
                        <option value="" disabled selected> Enter Source Entity</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in entities.entities" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div><div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitFormFirewall()">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And my JS looks like:

```
$scope.submitFormFirewall = function() {
            var postData = {};

            postData["index"] = $scope.firewallRuleID;
            postData["to"] = $scope.firewallDestination;
            postData["application"] = $scope.firewallApplication;
            postData["action"] = $scope.firewallAction;
            postData["from"] = $scope.firewallSource;
```

Comment: what *does* `value="{{key}}"` return?

Comment: @Claies: it returns a list values from my json object.

Comment: that sounds like real data to me?

Comment: @Claies: but when you POST it, it won't return anything. Its undefined.

Comment: ok, so the answer is it returns undefined.  where is the rest of the form to see what you are actually trying to send?

Comment: I really think you should probably be using `ngOptions` instead of `ngRepeat`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: `BUT when I POST the value I couldn't get anything. value="{{key}}" doesn't return a real data after POST` i don't understand this bit, you say after POST you don't see a real data yet there is no code example of what you do during POST

Comment: When I click submit, the selected value from options is undefined. No data that is on $scope.firewallSource @maurycy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="firewallSource" ng-options="obj.key as obj.value for obj in entities.entities">
    <option value=""> Enter Source Entity</option>
</select>
```

`key` and `value` are actually properties from your `entities[0]` object

Comment: It doesn't display the datas now.